# List of Figures displays ListofFigures

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

My list of figures is displaying as Listoffigures. How do I get the spaces to show in between the words

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{xesearch} %word count
\usepackage[margin=.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig} %landscape
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{epstopdf} %landscape
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{subcaption} %subfigure
\usepackage{caption} %subfigure
\usepackage{changepage} %indentsforquotes
\usepackage{lipsum} %indents for quotes
\usepackage{amsmath} %math
\usepackage{multirow} %table
\usepackage{longtable} %table
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref} %reference sections
\usepackage{array} %figure list
\graphicspath{{./Dissertation/}}
\usepackage{float}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % numebrs pages
\doublespacing %double spaced lines


%TO USE GREEK

\usepackage{textgreek} 
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifXeTeX
\usepackage{fontspec}
\else
\usepackage{luatextra}
\fi
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\setmainfont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*rm,ItalicFont=*ti,
BoldFont=*bx,BoldItalicFont=*bi,
]
\setsansfont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*ss,ItalicFont=*si,
BoldFont=*sx,BoldItalicFont=*so,
]
\setmonofont{cmun}[
Extension=.otf,UprightFont=*btl,ItalicFont=*bto,
BoldFont=*tb,BoldItalicFont=*tx,
]

%END OF GREEK

%word counter
\newcounter{words} %word count
\newenvironment{counted}{
\setcounter{words}{0}
\SearchList!{wordcount}{\stepcounter{words}}
{a?,b?,c?,d?,e?,f?,g?,h?,i?,j?,k?,l?,m?,n?,o?,p?,q?,r?,s?,t?,u?,v?,w?,x?,y?,z?}
\UndoBoundary{'}
\SearchOrder{p;}}{
\StopSearching}
%end word counter

%bib
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\pagebreak

\section{Acknowledgements}

words 

\hspace{6cm}
\vspace{5cm}
\begin{center}
\textit{words}
\end{center} 

\pagebreak

\section{Abstract}


\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

it looks like this when i generate my paper [image]

[image: this is the spins file picture]

I want it to show "list of figures"

Comment: the code you post clearly did not make the image you show that has the problem, and generates the error `! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option \`H'.` please check the posted code shows the problem you are asking about

Comment: edited to add \usepackage{float}; when creating mwe of my problem i forgot this

Comment: You could not forget things if you used the code posted. It now generates `! LaTeX Error: File \`spins' not found.` and  `! Undefined control sequence. l.15 \singlespacing` and if we for some reason ignore those errors it has only one figure in  the list and spaces in the heading. You clearly have not checked this code shows the problem. Please post an image _generated by the example shown_  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN8NX.png)

Comment: Spins is a figure on my computer - if you replace it with any other file title, it should run. i have uploaded it here. i have now updated the intro with all of my packages used and it shows the issue

Answer (score 1):

A more reasonable example would be

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}


%TO USE GREEK

\usepackage{polyglossia}


%bib


\begin{document}
% polyglossia bug?
%\renewcommand\listfigurename{List of Figures}


\listoffigures

\end{document}
```

You should report this to `polyglossia` but uncommenting the definition will fix the title.

Comment: probably better would be to actually set a language. The catcodes then seem to be right, they are only faulty if the default is loaded.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer sure but that wouldnt highlight the bug in the default language setting

Comment: I meant: a user should repair this by loading a language and not start to redefine all commands after begin document.